# Converting circular structure to JSON in a trivial Firebase Function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Error message: `Error: function crashed. Details:
Converting circular structure to JSON`

I receive the error despite a trivial code that should work. It must be something with regards to the Firebase modules, it seems. Here is my code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

export const addFxTransactionToFirestore = functions.https.onRequest(
    (req: any, res: any) => {
        console.log(req);
        res.send(req);
    }
);
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.1.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I just can't understand why it doesn't work and google has not been solving my problem either. Anyone with a clue?

Edit:
The JavaScript compiled code looks like this, just in case:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.addFxTransactionToFirestore = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    res.send(req);
});
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Comment: is this the only code you have? (this error wouldn't be related to the provided code). to verify if you comment out that code error should be gone

Comment: It's really the only code I have. What do you want me to comment out?

Comment: where did you put your firebase configs?

Comment: Where should I have put it? I didn't deliberately put it somewhere. I put the .json for the sdk in the main folder of the project.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: I thought this wasn't necessary for Firebase Functions that run in the cloud anyways. Link as source: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/uppercase-firestore/functions/index.js

Comment: So, this didn't cause the issue. The issue was caused by `console.log(req)`, which doesn't work for some reason.